# jthread vs std::async - what is the use-case for jthread over std::async

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I have just stumbled accross std::jthread: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread

Which *seems* to be solving the same problem as std::async/future has already solved (although you may need to force the behaviour of async `std::async(std::launch::async, ...` to run immediately.

So my question is what is the point of using one over the other? - is there some difference? is jthread a wrapper of async/future?

Comment: jthread models a thread, async models asynchronous execution and has IMO a better abstraction. The future allows you to pass information and errors back easily to the "calling" thread. Destructor of the future synchronizes, so I use usually use that in active objects (RAII pattern).

Comment: @PepijnKramer - that is what I think also.. so, why would they introduce `jthread` when (AFAICT) `std::async` is already better?

Comment: A good design rule of any library : Make the simple things simple (use abstractions) but make the harder (or more detailed) things not impossible. In this case async models an abstraction (a what), where you basically say I don't care how C++ does it (use an OS threadpool, a seperate process, or a new thread). With jthread you explicitly can design software to use a new physical thread for more detailed control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstractly, they are very similar. Assume that one uses `std::launch::async` and one does not call `std::jthread::detach`. They both accept synchronous functions and run them concurrently with the current thread of execution. They both provide a way to wait on the completion: `std::future::get` or `std::jthread::join`. They both implicitly and automatically perform the wait on destruction.

The differences are more about the particular details and guarantees.

It should be noted that `std::jthread` was added as a fix for `std::thread`. `std::thread` was added in C++11 alongside `std::async`, and the same question is valid for these. So, `std::async` had not "already" solved the problem, they were released together, as far as is relevant for this question. The problem with `std::thread` was that it required the user to always `join` or `detach` the thread, `detach` was always wrong, and if the user forgot to `join`, the program would terminate.

There is a meaningful difference in how values are returned. `std::async` must implicitly allocate a shared location for the return value. That isn't always necessary: sometimes you don't need a value, or sometimes you know that the asynchronous operation will complete before the current function returns (so, a captured stack variable suffices).

There is a meaningful difference between `std::future`s returned from `std::async` and those constructed some other way. The ones returned from `std::async` block on destruction, which is not the typical behavior. This complicates both the implementation and the mental model of `std::future`.

There is a meaningful difference in how exceptions are handled. Exceptions are propagated back with `std::async`.

Therefore, the comments are spot on. `std::async` can easily be implemented with `std::thread` or `std::jthread` so it is at a higher level. But conversely, `std::async` makes implicit choices which are not always optimal.